# Understanding indexes in the postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

PostgreSQL 9.4

I've read that the Index scan in `PostgreSQL` costs `2 * random_page_cost`(where `random_page_cost` is default sets to `4.0`). This's the thing that is not quite clear to me.

Reading [this page](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy/the-tree) about basic of indexes, I noticed that there might be more then 2-levels balanced trees in large tables.

So, if by creating an index we have `4-level` balanced tree, we'll have to read 4 random pages from the drive to return the result (which will cost `4 * random_page_cost`(One page for each level in the tree). Maybe I don't understand how the exact tree-traversal's performed, but this is my current understanding of the algorithm. Please, correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: What is "too broad" in that question?

Comment: _"I've read that the Index scan in PostgreSQL costs 2 * random_page_cost"_ - Where did you read that?